# HasComputedColumnSql() method not working as Expected

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have configured the `updatedAt` property as shown below. I expected that the `updatedAt` value of the corresponding row alone will change when inserting or updating. But when tried this it is updating entire column i.e all the rows of the `UpdatedAt` are getting changed which is not expected.

Am I doing any wrong configuration or it is the expected behavior.

```
modelbuilder.Entity<Author>()
            .Property(a => a.UpdatedAt)
            .HasComputedColumnSql("GetUtcDate()");
```

Comment: You're not defining a *default value* for the column to be used when no explicit value is present - you're defining a fixed, computed column - this column will **ALWAYS** be that particular value defined - for **ALL ROWS**.

Comment: You're looking for `HasDefaultValueSql("GetUtcDate()")`.